# $httpBackend Angular causing tests to fail with "No more request expected"

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

During refactoring of unit test dependencies, I've ran into this error happening over about 200ish tests that depend on angular-mocks with $httpBackend causing them to fail. I've looked through the call stack and it seems like $httpBackend.flush() is causing them to fail when trying attemptSync.

Here's what a test that is failing looks like, and this is what the error looks like:

Failing test:

```
fdescribe('UserPanelSettingsCtrl', function() {
   var $q, userPanelSettingsCtrl, scope, $httpBackend, WEBAPI_URL, MDAPI_URL, jstz;

beforeEach(function() {
    module('config');
    module('Core');
    module('utils');
});

beforeEach(function() {
    inject(function(_$q_, _$controller_, _$httpBackend_, _WEBAPI_URL_, _MDAPI_URL_, _$rootScope_, _jstz_) {
        $q = _$q_;
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        WEBAPI_URL = _WEBAPI_URL_;
        MDAPI_URL = _MDAPI_URL_;
        jstz = _jstz_;

        userPanelSettingsCtrl = _$controller_('UserPanelSettingsCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            user: {'profile':{'workgroups':{}}},
            jstz: jstz
        });
    });
});

beforeEach(function(){
    $httpBackend.expectGET(WEBAPI_URL + 'v1/users/me/settings/webui').respond({});
    $httpBackend.expectGET(MDAPI_URL + "v1/list/Mapped%20Megacomponent").respond([{id:1,name:'3D'}]);
    $httpBackend.expectGET(MDAPI_URL + "v1/list/Mapped%20Component").respond([{id:1,name:'D3D'}]);
});

afterEach(function(){
    angular.element('.toast').remove();
});

it('should load user settings and profile data from API ', function() {
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(scope.loading).toBe(false);
    expect(scope.verticals[0].id).toEqual(1);
    expect(scope.components[0].id).toEqual(1);
});
it('should save profile data to the API ', function() {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve();
    scope.user.updateWorkgroups = function(){ return deferred.promise; };
    scope.saveUserProfile({});
    $httpBackend.expectGET(WEBAPI_URL + 'v2/users/me').respond({});
    $httpBackend.expectPUT(WEBAPI_URL + 'v1/users/me/settings/webui').respond({});
    $httpBackend.flush();
    scope.$digest();

    expect(angular.element('.toast')).toBeDefined();
    expect(angular.element('.toast-message').text()).toEqual('User profile updated');

});`
```

And this is what the error looks like :

```
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows) UserPanelSettingsCtrl should load user settings and profile data from API  FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/web/v2/users/me
    No more request expected
        at $httpBackend (C:/Users/usr/Desktop/Karma Work - Copy/src/webui/public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1419:9)
        at sendReq (C:/Users/usr/Desktop/Karma Work - Copy/src/webui/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12027:9)
        at serverRequest (C:/Users/usr/Desktop/Karma Work - Copy/src/webui/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11822:16)
        at processQueue (C:/Users/usr/Desktop/Karma Work - Copy/src/webui/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16696:28)
        at C:/Users/usr/Desktop/Karma Work - Copy/src/webui/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16712:27
        at Scope.$eval (C:/Users/usr/Desktop/Karma Work - Copy/src/webui/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17994:28)
        at Scope.$digest (C:/Users/usr/Desktop/Karma Work - Copy/src/webui/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17808:31)
        at Scope.$apply (C:/Users/usr/Desktop/Karma Work - Copy/src/webui/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:18102:24)
        at done (C:/Users/usr/Desktop/Karma Work - Copy/src/webui/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12082:47)
        at Array.handleResponse (C:/Users/usr/Desktop/Karma Work - Copy/src/webui/public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1369:9)
```

Not sure how to go about solving this, I tried stepping through the call but I couldn't narrow down the issue. Might possibly be a dependency issue because I have been changing the file structure of where our dependencies are, and may have missed something in the grunt file that builds the app.

Comment: The error is saying that during the run of your app an HTTP call went out to `/api/web/v2/user/me` but you did not define a mock for it, which according to your tests is true. Of the three that you defined, none of them are to `/api/web/v2/user/me`

Comment: forgot to add that test in there, it's in there now

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting the `GET` after the call to `saveUserProfile` which calls the api with `/api/web/v2/user/me` url. So move the `$httpBackend.expectGET` up as shown below.

```
it('should save profile data to the API ', function() {
    $httpBackend.expectGET(WEBAPI_URL + 'v2/users/me').respond({});
    $httpBackend.expectPUT(WEBAPI_URL + 'v1/users/me/settings/webui').respond({});

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve();
    scope.user.updateWorkgroups = function(){ return deferred.promise; };
    scope.saveUserProfile({});

    $httpBackend.flush();
    scope.$digest();

    expect(angular.element('.toast')).toBeDefined();
    expect(angular.element('.toast-message').text()).toEqual('User profile updated');
});
```

Comment: Tried reordering the API calls, still didn't get any changes with the errors